# Excel - function to find the highest sum in a table using each row and column only once

Tags: excel-formula

I've got a table in excel with 10 rows and 10 columns.

The table contains 100 different values between 1 and 3.

I want to find the highest sum of 10 values using only 1 value from each row and 1 from each column.

Do u guys know a function that finds the highest sum? - I've tried to do i manually, but there are to many combinations!
Hope it makes sense.
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: I doubt that a formula will be able to do this.

Comment: DAMN, there are only 10! (3 628 800) combinations to check...

Comment: you could do it trough a bit of VBA but your question is tagged excel-formula

Comment: @ForwardEd I may be off base, but I get `13,168,189,440,000` different combinations. `100*81*64*49*36*25*16*9*4*1`

Comment: @ScottCraner  I took it as you had 10 columns to choose from for the first pick, 9 columns to choose from for the second pick and so on.  but I am not all that up and up on my permutations and combinations course.  I last touched that stuff late 80's. might have to verify it over on math stack exchange.  lets just say I am not going to write it out to check my answer.

Comment: @ForwardEd if you have a 10x10 or 100 cells and choose one you effectively remove one column and one row, 19 cells so you are down to 9^2 then 8^2 then 7^2 cells.  it is the number of cells that are available to choose not the number of columns.  But either way a formula or formulas will not be able to do this.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Took some more time to think about this.  Broke it down to a simpler model.  2X2 grid.  There are only two possible sums, top left and bottom right and then top right and bottom left.  2! =2,  2^2*1^2=4.  Interesting math problem.  may look pseudo could over the weekend for my own sake.  But alas not a formula option I can currently think of .

Comment: Tried the combinations for a 3x3 table and found 6=3! combinations. Guess im looking at 10! Combinations for this one.. Should I repost with vba tag er is this not worth trying to solve in excel?

Comment: No a 3X3 is 36.  First you have 9 to choose from then you have 4 then 1 it is 9*4*1

Comment: Even if the VBA solution doesn t look that simple, would you take it?

Comment: @user2196134 if you repost with vba you will be expected to have shown some preliminary attempts at solving this on your own.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you find first the maximum value in the 10x10 array, then the maximum in the 9x9 array (excluding the row/column of the first maximum), etc., this cannot be that difficult to do ??

Comment: Regarding the 3x3 table: pretty sure u can only find 6 combinations (although we can agree upon 3^2*2^2=36). Guess I wont find an answer. - dont know more than a few basics about vba.. thanks to all of you for your inputs:)

Comment: @user2196134 You say "different values". So it is a given that all 100 numbers different, or can there be duplicates ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

My solution builds on what I wrote in the comment, i.e. you first take the maximum value in the 10x10 array, then the maximum in the 9x9 array (excluding the row/column of the first maximum), etc.  My solution tries not to do everything in one formula, but I add a few helper columns, and a bit more helper rows (it is fast and dirty, but it works and is easily audited/understandable). You always can do this on a separate worksheet which you could hide if needed.

The screenshot above goes from cell A1 till Y31.

The key formulas:

- 3.55 is the result of `=MAX(B2:K11)`
- The first gray cell is `=IFNA(MATCH($M12;B2:B11;0);"")`, and you drag this 9 cells to the left. This tries to find a match with the max result in each column of the table;
- The 10 left of the 3.55 is `=MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(ISNUMBER(P12:Y12);0);0)` , and gives the column number of the max value.
- The 2 next to the 10 is `=INDEX(P12:Y12;N12)` and gives the row number of the max value.
- The 1 in cell B12 is `=IF(OR(B$1=$N12;$A12=$O12);0;1)`, and creates a 10x10 matrix with a row and column with zeroes where the previous max value was found.
- Then you multiply this with the preceding matrix and create a new 10x10 matrix below (enter `{=B2:K11*B12:K21}` array formula (ctrl+shift+enter) in B22-K31
- You then copy/paste rows 12 till 31 9 times below
- The 23.02 is the total sum `=SUM($M$12:$M$211)` from all 10 maximum values and is the result you are looking for. The 10 is just a check with `=COUNT($M$12:$M$211)`